# SQL Server login failed for user client computer

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using SQL Server r2 database as a remote server having mixed mode sql authentication.

When run my c# program from client computer to access database with following connection string:

```
"Data Source=192.168.1.101\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial Catalog=Login; Integrated Security=true;Connection timeout=30; User ID=sa;Password=23456"
```

and facing an error:

> Login failed for user 'VAIO\Guest'.

VAIO is remote PC.

Comment: does the error message say why the login failed? where did you find the message? I think you need to show your implementation, because your connection string is attempting to connect to the database as `sa` (which is a bad idea in general), but your error message is talking about `VAIO\Guest`.

Comment: Are you accepting remote access on the sql server?

Answer (score 4):

you are using `Integrated Security=true` which denotes that sql will try to login using Windows authentication. It seems that this windows user is not a valid login for sql server. If you want to use user and password set:

```
Integrated Security=false
```

Comment: +1 Also it doesn't make any sense for the connection string to say use windows auth, then provide a username and password later on...

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me. use Sa user id and password...

````
"Data Source=192.168.8.106\PEBB, 1433;Initial Catalog=d2;Integrated Security=False;user id=sa;password=123;Connect Timeout=30"```
````

Answer (score -1):

Add one space before port no.
Data Source=192.168.1.101\SQLEXPRESS, 1433